# Erro ao colocar ImageButtons com sons dentro de fragment

Tags: android

Estou tentando colocar ImageButtons tocando sons dentro de um fragment chamado Tab1, porém estou encontrando dois erros:

> Non-static method 'findViewById(int)' cannot be referenced from a
>   static context

na linha

`final ImageButton vitasbut = tab1.findViewById(R.id.vitasbut);`

e

> Cannot resolve method
>   'create(com.example.mateuspc1.memepocket.MainActivity.Tab1, int)'

nas linhas                     `mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gtaintro);` (em todos os mediaPlayer.create).

Código:

```
public static class Tab1 extends Fragment {
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);



        }
        public Tab1() {
            final ImageButton vitasbut = tab1.findViewById(R.id.vitasbut);

            vitasbut.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    vitasbut.setImageResource(R.drawable.vitas1);
                    play(vitasblblblahahah);
                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            vitasbut.setImageResource(R.drawable.vitas1e2);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });}

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        private final String gtaintro = "gtaintro";
        private final String gtaagaraga = "gtaagaraga";
        private final String bolsdaqeut = "bolsdaqeut";
        private final String vitasblblblahahah = "vitasblblblahahah";
        private final String vitasuoah = "vitasuoah";
        private final String gabedogbark = "gabedogbark";
        private final String bolsetemqsef = "bolsetemqsef";
        private final String acertomizeravi = "acertomizeravi";
        private final String aiaichoque = "aiaichoque";
        private final String bnsetimaarte = "bnsetimaarte";
        private final String fausterou = "fausterou";
        private final String fausttapegfog = "fausttapegfog";

        private void play(String theText) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                if (Objects.equals(theText, gtaintro))
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gtaintro);

                else if (Objects.equals(theText, gtaagaraga))
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gtaagaraga);

                else if (Objects.equals(theText, bolsdaqeut))
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bolsdaqeut);

                else if (Objects.equals(theText, vitasblblblahahah))
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.vitasblblblahahah);

                else if (Objects.equals(theText, vitasuoah))
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.vitasuoah);

                else if (Objects.equals(theText, gabedogbark))
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gabedogbark);

                else if (Objects.equals(theText, bolsdaqeut))
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bolsdaqeut);

                else if (Objects.equals(theText, bolsetemqsef))
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bolsetemqsef);

                else if (Objects.equals(theText, acertomizeravi))
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.acertomizeravi);

                else if (Objects.equals(theText, aiaichoque))
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.aiaichoque);

                else if (Objects.equals(theText, bnsetimaarte))
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bnsetimaarte);

                else if (Objects.equals(theText, fausterou))
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fausterou);

                else if (Objects.equals(theText, fausttapegfog))
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fausttapegfog);
            }
            assert mediaPlayer != null;
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Experimenta ->  final ImageButton vitasbut = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.vitasbut);

Comment: Funcionou. Coloquei logo acima de public Tab1() { etc etc etc }. Muito obrigado. =)
Alguma ideia sobre o problema do método create? Creio que eu precise substituir o "this", mas não sei pelo quê. (vi numas respostas pelo stack overflow)

Comment: Já tentaste fazer o  Clean do projecto?

Comment: Não. Acabei de fazer e continuou igual. :/

Comment: Okay... Tenta substituir o `this` por  `getActivity().getContext()`

Comment: Postado também no [StackOverflow EN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49118366/5861618)

Comment: Consegui fazer rodar, porém deu crash no app dizendo 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
na linha         final ImageButton vitasbut = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.vitasbut);


Oi Rosário! =) O que postei lá foi pra saber como rodar o código dentro do fragment; aqui estou postando pra corrigir outros erros. Achei que se postasse os erros naquele mesmo post, daria algum problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os `Fragment` trabalha de uma forma diferente de uma `Activity`:

Na construção da Activity, utilizamos o  método [onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html?hl=pt-br), onde informamos qual `xml` vamos usar através do método [setContentView(android.view.View)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html?hl=pt-br#setContentView(android.view.View)).

Já na construção do `Fragment`, utilizamos o método [onCreateView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html?hl=pt-br#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)), onde retornamos a `View`  da tela.

Devido a isto, o Fragment não possui o método `findViewById` e sim a View (retornada no método `onCreateView()`).

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
     final ImageButton vitasbut = view.findViewById(R.id.vitasbut);
     // Seu código com o botão vitasbut...
    return view;
}
```

Não recomendo a usar o Construtor do `Fragment` para inicializar os objetos em tela, pois ele é invocado antes de Construir a tela (chamar o método `onCreateView()`).